# NGINX - Forward everything to a php script

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I'm trying to forward every request to the same php script.

I came up with this configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/html;

    index api.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /api.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index api.php;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

While it works, it still allows direct access to resources if the correct $uri is provided.

If I try to change the first location block to this:

```
location / {
    try_files /api.php$is_args$args =404;
}
```

It doesn't work, always returns 404.

Comment: I take it `/var/www/html/api.php` exists? If you visit it directly, does it work?

Comment: Actually this is exactly what it should do: "allows direct access to resources if the correct $uri is provided". It's usually better to let Nginx handle static file delivery (e.g. images) compared to a PHP process. But I assume you like to have more that that: (1) Do you want to forward requests for static files to PHP for some purposes? (2) Do you want to forward requests for PHP files to one single PHP script?

Comment: @JensBradler Yes, I want to forward everything to the same PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```nginx
server {
    server_name example.com;

    root "/var/www/html";

    location / {
        include "fastcgi_params";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/api.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME api.php;
        fastcgi_index api.php;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

If the aim is to forward all the requests to a single PHP script and if that single PHP script is known in advance by its name, then we don't need a separate location block. Only one location block that sends all the requests to that known PHP script is enough.

`fastcgi_split_path_info` is not needed, when the PHP script to be executed is not known in advance and is available only as part of the URI.

Also, `try_files $uri =404` isn't needed since that known PHP script is already available at a fixed / known place.